# How to check when reading files from HDFS which is already read and which is not

Tags: java, hadoop

I am writing files to folder in hdfs continously and another program reading the files from the same folder continously.How to check in reading program from hdfs whether the file which i am reading is already read or not . If already read check for another file. Java Programmatically

Comment: [I haven't worked on hadoop.] My Suggestion is, can you make a Sqlite table and every time you read file, save the filename in that table, next you read a file check if that exist in the table and based on that you can read + update table or ignore the file.

Comment: I want it through java program I am reading a sigle folder presently , I dont know how to approach If any one can tell me ..The approach